# How to calculate the Feynman diagram under $SU(N_c)$ group?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, quantum-chromodynamics

I give my own answer below. I use the feynman rules for QCD directly to calculate the process: $qq'\rightarrow qq'$, where $q$ and $q'$ have different flavor. But I don't how to give my answer consistent with the standard answer.
It seems that the standard answer is based on the $SU(N_c)$ group?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is about how to get the quadratic Casimir in the amplitude : in the Feynman rules to each 2 fermion-gluon vertex there corresponds a generator $T^a$. And you have to sum over all possible colors in each vertex. As written in the formula for amplitude you get a contribution $\sum_a T^a T^a$, which is actually a quadratic Casimir $C_f$, that commutes with all generators and due to Schur lemma is proportional to identity. The factor $1/N_f$ corresponds, as far as I understand, to the average over colors.

Comment: Thanks! Following your analysis, we calculated out the quadratic colour factor, which yielded the $C_f$  and $N_c$ if I considered $SU(N_C)$ group. So far, the exercises I have done are about quarks with colours, like incoming quarks with red or blue color. It is the first time I meet this case